# I'm trying to inner a table in SQL (tera term) but something displayed was not as my expected

Tags: sql

[I think it should display the value (Adventure genre) that I put below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AsBp.png)

Comment: Please add more info on your question, what did you try, what results did you get, what is your expected result. Putting an image link is not a good way to ask question in SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some help.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Service( servicelD varchar(10)CONSTRAINT servicelD_pk PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
actorlD varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
directorlD varchar(10)
NOT NULL, 
title varchar(40), 
console varchar(10), 
genre varchar(15), 
dateRelease date)
insert into Service
values ('S-1011003', 'A-03', '100103-01', 'The Iron Man', 'Blu-ray', 'Adventure', '28-SEP-07') 

create table Actor ( actorlD varchar(10) CONSTRAINT actorlD_pk PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, actorRole varchar(20)); 
insert into Actor
values ('A-03', 'Supporting Actor') 

select s.servicelD, a.actorlD, s.title, s.genre, a.actorRole  from [service] s 
left join actor a on a.actorlD = s.actorlD
where s.genre = 'Adventure'; 
--
drop table Actor
drop table Service
```

Comment: still, no rows selected

Comment: you are inserting 'adventure' in genre columns.change where condition to where genre = 'Adventure';